# How to encode a query string when using _path helpers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I currently have this snippet:

```
edit_case_path(@case, {:name => @case.name})
```

which generates a path like this:

```
/cases/4/edit?name=johnson
```

But to make things more invisible to the user, i'd like my path to be something like this:

```
/cases/4/edit?asdfjhsdfiojpasfdoj
```

where `asdfjhsdfiojpasfdoj` is basically some sort of encoding (base64?) that can be decoded to `name=johnson`.

How can I do this using the `_path` helpers?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a native way to do that with the path-helpers, but you could do something like:

```
edit_case_path(@case, {:q => base64_encode({:name => @case.name})})
```

with a helper like:

```
require 'base64'
def base64_encode(args)
  Base64.encode64(args)
end
```

and then in your controller:

```
args =  Base64.decode64(params[:q])
```

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/base64/rdoc/Base64.html

Answer (score 1):

Base64 would not protect you from anything really. Also I don't think you can get away with encoding the url to the client. But if the point is not to let him see the URL at the browser, you should use the HTTP POST method instead of GET. POST sends the same parameters in the body of the request instead of in the URL string. You can configure that in your routes file.

Comment: This is a simple link on a website. POST is not the correct usage in this use case.

Comment: I know it's not the correct usage. But, hey, neither is encoding the URL data with user data from the user. Still think POST is much better IMHO.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with encoding url with data from a user. Using a POST is a more complicated solution that what is needed. At worst case scenario i just don't use the `_path` helper and manually generate my url with a link like this: `<%= link_to 'my link', "/cases/4/edit/#{encoded_var}" ...` but my question is specifically asking how to encode a query string when using the `_path` helpers. I'm just curious if it's possible or if I need to manually generate my link.

Comment: Using POST is complicated? You can get the params the same way you get with GET, plus no data in the url. Sorry, I dont get it, what are the drawbacks in this case?

Answer (score 1):

**Route**

To further `Tiago Farias`'s answer, I would ask why are you trying to pass a parameter in the route like that anyway?

Rails operates on a [resource-based structure](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) (especially with its routes), which means if you're loading the `edit` route, this *should* be loading a `resource`, right?

I simply don't understand why you're having to pass a parameter to the `edit` action - surely the `edit` action, is there for you to *edit* a resource / object. In this case, you'd be able to populate the `name` attribute from the resource itself

--

**Helpers**

If you wanted to use the path helpers like you are, I see no issue in how you're passing the param (from a functionality perspective)

If you wanted to "encode" the URL somehow, you'd be best using one of the encoding pattern like `base64` (as recommended by `Taryn East`). The question is then not about *"how do I create the path"*, but *"how do I create the encoded param?"*

If you wanted to pass the parameter, you can use the `link_to` method as you described:

```
<% name = [[encoding here]] %>
<%= link_to "Your Path", edit_path(@var, {name: name}) %>
```

Comment: I want to pass the name through the url as part of the workflow. A user is on a page viewing an event for a specific name and then they want to create a "case" for that family name so i'm passing the name through the url so it will auto populate the name on the "case" form.

Comment: The problem with encoding the name and then passing it as a param to the edit_path helper as you've shown is that the url will look like this `/case/4/edit?name=asdflkjsfdjkdsf`. I don't want `name` to even be in the url.

Comment: Hey Tom :) okay So you want to "predefine" the name from the link?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "predefine" the name from the link. All i want is a clickable link where the url looks like this: `/cases/4/edit?asdfjhsdfiojpasfdoj` where `asdfjhsdfiojpasfdoj` decodes to `name=johnson`.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was that you could send name as a POST request - allowing you to process it in the controller backend? If you want to go into chat to sort this out, I believe we can do it